# /gazebo/model_states yields incorrect orientation for cube

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to access the pose of cube in gazebo using `/gazebo/model_states`. There is a large error between the reported result by `/gazebo/model_states` and Gazebo GUI. Take a look at the following picture. The GUI shows 0.758 and  `/gazebo/model_states` gives 0.369. I need to use this data as ground truth but from what I'm noticing, I need to make sure there is no discrepancy. Any suggestions?

Melodic, Gazebo 9, Ubuntu 18.04.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406147//gazebo/model_states-yields-incorrect-orientation-for-cube/) by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2022-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These look correct to me. Gazebo is reporting axis-angle in radians, while /gazebo/model_states is reporting quaternions. You can do a manual transform here to see that they are the same: https://www.andre-gaschler.com/rotationconverter/.

---

Originally posted by [Ronoman](https://answers.ros.org/users/56810/ronoman/) with karma: 48 on 2022-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1